# How do I prove by induction that for all $(n\ge2)\in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}>\sqrt{n}.$?

Tags: summation, induction

I understand how to prove the base case $n = 2$. So far, I have figured out that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} > \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}.$$

Comment: Well, you should show that $\sqrt n + \frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}} \ge \sqrt{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $n+1>n$ so $n(n+1)>n^2$ for $n>2$. Hence $\sqrt{n(n+1)} \geq n$ so $$\sqrt{n(n+1)} + 1 \geq n+1 \iff \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq \sqrt{n+1}$$

That is $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} > \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq \sqrt{n+1}$$

completing the induction.

Answer (score 1):

A simply simpler variant for the inductive step:

Suppose for a certain $n\ge 2$, we have $\;\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}>\sqrt n$. Then , as you deduced
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}>\sqrt n+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}.$$
Now $\;\sqrt n+\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\ge\sqrt{n+1}$, since it is equivalent to
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\le\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}.$$